# Ask variable condition if terraform apply or destroy

Tags: terraform

How can I set an input varible to only be asked if terraform apply is introduced in the terminal?

There is no value set in tfvars because I want this variable to be interactive. I only want that this variable only be asked in the terminal when I enter terraform apply but not when I enter terraform destroy. I see that the condition maybe do the job but I do not know how.

Thank you very much

```
variable "example" {
    description = "Test"
    sensitive = true
}
```

Comment: We will need more details than that. Please make sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Laiust Are you trying to pass that particular variable only during the `terraform apply`?

Comment: In this case, you just need to run `terraform apply` and you will be asked for input.

Comment: Yes, I know that when I ran terraform apply it will be asked the variable. What I do not want is when I run terraform destroy, the variable is also asked again in the terminal. I want somehow that when I ran terraform destroy, that variable is not asked.

Comment: So what is it exactly what you want to achieve? Is that some variable you don't want to type in because it's sensitive?

Comment: I exactly want that when I enter terraform apply, the variable is asked, but, when I enter terraform destroy, I do not want that variable to be asked.

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible.

Comment: terraform have an outstanding bug to do this: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/30238

Answer (score -3):

When input variables are declared in your terraform configuration, the values can be set in a number of ways. In your case, you can try the command-line option as below

`terraform apply -var example="YOUR_VALUE"`

Also, `terraform destroy` will not prompt for this variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, but that solution do not solve the problem. What i need is that when I enter terraform destroy, the input variable not be asked, somehow, skip that variable in terraform destroy.

Comment: There is no use of invoking a variable "example" while destroy, that's point.